# Is there a way to search through the lists in your code searching for an input in one of them?

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to get an input and search multiple lists within my code for that value, like so:

```
a = ["apple", "fruit", "round"]
b = ["banana", "fruit", "long"]
needed_list = lists_in_code.search("apple")    # locates list a
print(needed_list[2])    # would print "round"
```

In my code, I will be using many more lists, more than 100 in total. Is there a way to get an input (e.g. "apple") and access the list that contains it (e.g. a) to use another element from the list (e.g. "fruit" or "round")with only this piece of data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried on this problem? Are you familiar with dictionaries within Python? That might be a better way to store this data.

Comment: I think it would be better if you use a dictionary with name of fruits as key and the properties as a list of value.

Comment: I agree with the one answer below, you should probably improve the design of your code. There should be no reason that you need a method of finding a value in this manner. Create a structure and object hierarchy that allow you to define this kind of complex behavior in a more manageable way. Also, if you're storing this number of lists - the obvious answer would be to create a class that contains lists. This class could then have a functuon "search()" that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably improve the design of your code. That said, here you go:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ["apple", "fruit", "round"]
>>> b = ["banana", "fruit", "long"]
>>> loc = dict(locals())
>>> [v for k, v in loc.iteritems() if isinstance(v, list) and 'apple' in v]
[['apple', 'fruit', 'round']]
>>>
```

You might also want to use globals. References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better data structure for this problem, depending on your requirements.

To address the specific question, loop through the lists, and return the list (if any) containing your term for further processing.

```
def find_list_with_term(term):
    all_lists = [
        ["apple","fruit","round"],
        ["banana","fruit","long"]
        ...
    ]

    for li in all_lists:
        if term in li:
            return li

list_with_term = find_list_with_term("apple")
print list_with_term
>> ["apple","fruit","round"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of lists like

```
a=apple,fruit,round
b=banana,fruit,long
c=a,b
```

Now, iterate list c and whatever child list (a or b) contains the required search string (apple), return that list.